# Custom ResultSetTableModel not displaying results in JXTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have modified [this code](https://github.com/Chora10/Cknife/blob/master/src/com/ms509/model/ResultSetTableModel.java) with the hope that it will do what I want. However it is not displaing results in the JXTable.

**MY POJO**

```
public class Product {
private String stockCode;
private String name;
private String description;
private String category;
private String type;
private Double price;
private Integer quantity;
//getters and setters -auto generated.
}
```

**This is my Custom Model**

```
public class ResultSetTableModelProduct extends AbstractTableModel {

private ResultSet rs;
private ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
private List<String> title;
private List<Product> datas;
private int colcount = 0;

public ResultSetTableModelProduct(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        this.rs = rs;
        this.rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        this.colcount = this.rsmd.getColumnCount();
        title = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 1; j <= this.colcount; j++) {
            title.add(this.rsmd.getColumnName(j));
        }
        title.set(0, "Stock Code");
        title.set(1, "Name");
        title.set(2, "Desc");
        title.set(3, "type");
        title.set(4, "cat");
        title.set(5, "Price");
        title.set(6, "Quantity");

        datas = new Vector<Product>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product pro = new Product();

            pro.setStockCode(rs.getString("stock_code"));
            pro.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            pro.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            pro.setType(rs.getString("type_code"));
            pro.setCategory(rs.getString("cat_code"));
            pro.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            pro.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));
            System.out.println("Product name:" + pro.getName());//this is printing fine
            datas.add(pro);
            System.out.println("Is there Data in datas? " + datas);//Yes, printing too

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.get(column);

}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.size();
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return datas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Product p = new Product();
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return p.getStockCode();
        case 1:
            return p.getName();
        case 2:
            return p.getDescription();
        case 3:
            return p.getType();
        case 4:
            return p.getCategory();
        case 5:
            return p.getPrice();
        case 6:
            return p.getQuantity();
        default:
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(column);
    }
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {

    if (col < 0 || col >= this.getColumnCount()) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(col);
    } else {
        Product p = new Product();
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                p.setStockCode(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 1:
                p.setName(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                p.setDescription(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 3:
                p.setType(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 4:
                p.setCategory(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 5:
                p.setPrice((Double) aValue);
                break;
            case 6:
                p.setQuantity((Integer) aValue);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(col);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;//stcode
        case 1:
            return String.class;//name
        case 2:
            return String.class;//desc
        case 3:
            return String.class;//typecode
        case 4:
            return String.class;//cat
        case 5:
            return Double.class;//price
        case 6:
            return Integer.class;//quantity
        default:
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
    }
}

public void addRow(Product product) {
    this.datas.add(product);
    this.fireTableRowsInserted(datas.size() - 1, datas.size() - 1);
    //also add into
}

public void remove(String id) {
    //remove both from the model and DB
}

}
```

**And here is how I am initializing my table and GUI**

```
//set your table here
    connection=conn.getConnection();
    stmnt=connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet res=stmnt.executeQuery(sql);
    rsp= new ResultSetTableModelProduct(res);
    jXTable1_products.setModel(rsp);
```

So when I run my application, it is running fine but only the entries/data not shown in the table. **What have am I missing**?
Also find extra infor in comments.

Comment: What are the rowCount and columnCount of your table model? Does the data display in a JTable?  Instead of getting data from the database, first test your code by manually adding a Product object to your "datas" ArrayList. Do you add the table to a scrollpane? Do you add the scrollpane to a frame? You need to do basic debugging. We don't have access to your data.

Comment: @camickr  rowCount returns the no of rows, columnCount the number of cols. ***The data does not display in the JTable***<--And that is my question. Yes, manual code is adding Products to `datas` --check the comments in the contsructor. I added the table using drag drop in NetBeans.

Comment: The posted code looks reasonable, but we don't know the context of how all the code is used. Maybe you create two tables or two scrollpanes. So first get your code working with a plain JTable using the DefaultTableModel. If that doesn't work then you post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Since we have access to all the standard JDK classes we can help find the problem. Once that works you change the DefaultTableModel to your custom model with hard coded data. Once that works you replace the hard coded data with the SQL logic.

Comment: @camickr  When I remove my `CustomTableModel` and put [this one](https://github.com/Chora10/Cknife/blob/master/src/com/ms509/model/ResultSetTableModel.java) it works fine. As regarding SQL logic, I can say it is fine because it is pulling the `column names` from the DB table. It is only the data that is not showing, so I thought I missed something. Anyway, let me try what you have said.

Comment: Getting the columns names is easy. Getting the data is harder since you need a proper where clause. However it is easy to verify you just add debug code in the loop[ that reads the data from the ResultSet. The point is "don't guess". Do some basic debugging to determine "where" the problem is.

Comment: @camickr You see `System.out.println("Is there Data in datas? " + datas);//Yes, printing too` this statement is printing data in the `datas` after populating the `datas` from `ResultSet` `res`. This `System.out.println("Product name:" + pro.getName());//this is printing fine` too is printing each product name while i am in my `while loop` to see if there is data pushed into the `res`.

Comment: @camickr So, with that `can say` data is being added into the `List` by name `data`. So the problem is `showing the data to the JTable`. I thought I missed a `paint or something method` that renders data to the JTable..